# What's wrong with Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.10 - network locations not showing?

Tags: networking, nautilus

Using Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak), and in 'other places' networking won't show. I have three [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) servers which refuse to show.

They will show in Windows and Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus), but all my machines running 16.10 won't show them. As a workaround I have removed Nautilus and installed Nemo as a file manager, and I can now access all my network shares with no issue. This to me points to an issue in Nautilus 3.20.

I reverted back to Nautilus to try some more. I can see all my shares now, however it hangs on opening any shared folder at the 'Opening [*folder name*]' 'You can stop this operation by clicking cancel'. Nemo opened them all instantly, but it results in issues with desktop manipulation! In a terminal Nautilus gives the following outputs:

```
(nautilus:5038): Glib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections !=NULL' failed . The line is down twice.
```

Comment: raise a bug and report https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus

Comment: If you start nautilus in a terminal and perform that action, is there any debug output in the terminal?

Comment: I reverted back to Nautilus to try some more. I can see all my shares now, however it hangs on opening any shared folder at the 'Opening [folder name]' 'You can stop this operation by clicking cancel'. Nemo opened them all instantly, but gives issues with desktop manipulation!